# Scripts executed multiple times running on Google Managed VM's

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-managed-vm

I'm fairly new at google cloud and node. Based on Google's recommendation (the requirement to watch Firebase at all times) I deployed managed VM node app, instead of just app engine. There are now 22-23 instances every time I deploy. Is this expected? I thought it would only scale when necessary.

This node app has a method which watches Firebase variables and change, in turn, the script fires off a notification.

What happens now is that multiple notifications are being fired and I only expect one. I suspect it's because there are multiple instances of this app.

What is the right way to do this so that only one is watching?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it may be difficult for the auto-scaler to detect when it is necessary to spin up more instances. Since you're expecting a single instance, I'd switch to manual scaling: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services

Comment: Check out [Firebase Queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) for synchronizing tasks between many node workers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method suggested by google for flexible server environments and firebase. https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible and https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/06/learn-to-build-a-mobile-backend-service-with-Firebase-and-App-Engine.html .

Have the instance "claim users" by transactioning it's instance ID at a location where the user can reach it and send updates to that instance by setting the instanceID in the path.